# I have a repository in AWS codeartifact. I want to retrieve a jar from the repository in my sbt project

Tags: scala, maven, jar, sbt, aws-codeartifact

I have a repository in AWS codeartifact, i'm able to publish jars there successfully. Now, i want to retrieve that jar in my sbt project. Trying this in local gives me not found.

In order for my local project to be able to retrieve from codeArtifact i have added credentials( codeArtifact authToken ) and resolvers( codeArtifact repository location and repository name ) in build.sbt .

the error i am getting is : -

[error] coursier.ResolutionException: Encountered 1 error(s) in dependency resolution:
[error]     com.tusfi.tusplatform.commons:tg-commons_2.11:1.0.0-snapshot:
[error]         not found:
[error]https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/tusfi/tusplatform/commons/tg-commons_2.11/1.0.0-snapshot/tg-commons_2.11-1.0.0-snapshot.pom

It looks to me that my build is trying to retrieve the jar from maven central repository instead of looking in the custom resolver that i provided. I am able to perform list-repository command successfully from CLI so i am assuming that i have permission to this repo.
Can you tell me if there is any permission issue? If not, then what seems to be the issue here?

Also if it helps, codeArtifact policy :
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
},
"Action": "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository",
"Resource": "*"
}
]
}